# Looking to store two different web urls in a data structure

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming

I have two URLs containing the 'hello' string.

```
https://us.search.yahoo.com/search?p=%22hello%22&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8
```

and

```
https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=hello&oq=hello&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5
```

I'm looking to write a function that would take a search engine name parameter and a string in a Python function with these URLs above so that a user can use `search_keyword(yahoo, 'hello')` or `search_keyword(google, 'hello')`

The difficulty I currently have is that I work with different URL formats for a same URL like inserting double-quotes in them to customize searching like in Google or other engine. But this adds to the number of different URLs I have to work with to try and create a function that would be flexible enough to take different URL formats into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the different search formats into a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), using the search engine name as the key. Then use placeholders for parts of the search URL that can be [`replaced`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) later from function inputs. Example, for the query string, use `__QUERY__` as a placholder.

```py
url_format = {
    "yahoo": "https://us.search.yahoo.com/search?p=__QUERY__&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8",
    "google": "https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=__QUERY__&oq=__QUERY__&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5"
}
```

For the inputs to replace the placeholders, you can use [`urllib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) to format the input to be compatible for URLs.

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus("hello")
'hello'
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus('"quoted text"')
'%22quoted+text%22'
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus("spec|@l ch@arac+3r$")
'spec%7C%40l+ch%40arac%2B3r%24'
>>>
```

Putting it all together:

```py
import urllib.parse

def search_keyword(engine_name, query_string):
    # Store formats for each search engine with placeholders
    url_format = {
        "yahoo": "https://us.search.yahoo.com/search?p=__QUERY__&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8",
        "google": "https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=__QUERY__&oq=__QUERY__&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5"
    }

    url = url_format[engine_name]
    # Make sure to handle the case where the dict does not contain engine_name (KeyError)

    # Format the input params for URL use
    query_key = "__QUERY__"
    query = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query_string)

    # Replace placeholders
    url = url.replace(query_key, query)

    print(url)

search_keyword("yahoo", "hello")
# https://us.search.yahoo.com/search?p=hello&fr=yfp-t&fp=1&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8

search_keyword("google", "this has spaces")
# https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=this+has+spaces&oq=this+has+spaces&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5

search_keyword("google", '"quoted text"')
# https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=%22quoted+text%22&oq=%22quoted+text%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5

search_keyword("google", "spec|@l ch@arac+3r$")
# https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&sxsrf=ACYBGNQKbsRTGVazpquHLRnglPuOj1xW9w%3A1576297488275&source=hp&ei=EGT0XcCLDoj4abrUjcAF&q=spec%7C%40l+ch%40arac%2B3r%24&oq=spec%7C%40l+ch%40arac%2B3r%24&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i203l9.1236.2231..2801...1.0..0.56.247.5......0....1..gws-wiz.......0.LoDd2hNQIFQ&ved=0ahUKEwjA0-LepbTmAhUIfBoKHTpqA1gQ4dUDCAU&uact=5
```

Comment: Wow, thanks very much Gino. Great answer. It makes sense to me now. I will implement this as of now.

Comment: A quick question, can the "search_keyword("yahoo", "hello")" be called in a for loop or while loop iterating over a file rather than hardcoding the "hello" string? Thanks.

Comment: @timotom Yes, you can. `search_keyword` is a function, accepting 2 string arguments, the `engine_name` and the `query_string`. You can loop over each line of a file, get the engine name and the query string from the current line, then call `search_keyword` passing in the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. So far, I've been adding the functionalities. (1) I saved the  keywords in file with a for loop that can (2) open the browser windows, but not being able to (3) change the engine name. Now, I can do (2) and (3) but not (1). I'm on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @timotom Try a file format that's easy to parse line by line, [like a CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), where each line has the params separated by a `delimiter=','`, like this `yahoo,hello,other-params`.